# What to consider when looking for a chainguard?

Tags: crankset, accessories

Alright, the inner seam of my jeans is about done for, and I'm worried that I'll take a nasty spill the next time my pants get caught in there. Given that I don't want to wear gaiters or Lycra, I'm looking to install a chain guard on my bike (2014 Novara Safari).

What are some of the things to consider when looking for a chainguard? I know that front derailleur compatibility is a major issue. What else?

Comment: Why not just use a velcro tie on your drive side pant leg?

Comment: Like I said, I'm exploring options besides Lycra and gaiters (which is effectively what a velcro tie would be). If I can find a decent chainguard at a decent price, I'd prefer that to having to use a gaiter on my daily commute.

Comment: But a chain guard is not going to do that.  What is wrong with a tie?

Comment: @Blam because the ideal solution means doing something once (installing a magic widget on the bicycle) and never thinking on it again.  Putting a tie/strap/gaiter on requires intervention on each trip and is less than convenient.  What's required is a full shield that guards the whole of the crankset, and in general a good version of such a thing doesn't exist that I know of.

Comment: @ChrisinAK Why are you addressing me?   If you have an ideal solution then post it.  I have not found a three speed chain guard that saves pants.  Even a guard on my single speed saves my chain ring but not save my pants.

Comment: @Blam I was just addressing your question of what was wrong with a tie.  As I said, I haven't yet seen an ideal solution, which is why I didn't post an answer.  There are many "ideal solutions" for cycling that no one manufacturers because of either niche market issues, or cost issues.  I think the take away here is that you can either deal with a tie, or deal with there not being a great solution on the market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bought 2 of [these half chaincases](http://www.dutchbikebits.com/mudguards-chainguards-fenders-coatprotectors/de-woerd-wave-chaincase):

One of them is fitted to my wife's commuting mtb and does the job of keeping trouser legs and shoe laces out of the chain rings (with a guard disc fitted to the cranks as standard). I just couldn't get it to fit my hybrid without rubbing on the chain (and it was fiddly on the mtb). Both have 28-38-48 chain rings and i don't think it would fit anything bigger.

I think the reason I couldn't get it on mine was the *length* of the chain run (it's an XL frame) possibly combined with the 11--32 tooth cassette. The shape of the crank arms might have something to do with it as well -- clearances are tight. You should consider ease of fitting/opening/removal for working on the chain, compared with how often you need access to the top of the chain run. You may find that it's *more* total effort than a clip or tucking your trouser leg into your sock every ride.

There are similar chain guards out there. She's got an e-bike with one on. It looks like it would fit 2 chain rings but not 3 and has not branding on it.